# Traversing a 2D array and finding "enclosed rooms"

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a 2D array that looks like this:

```
var map = [
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [2,2,2,0,2,2,0,0,0,0],
    [2,2,2,0,2,2,0,0,0,0],
    [0,1,0,0,2,2,1,1,1,0],
    [0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0],
    [0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
];
```

I can't figure out how to traverse the array so I can detect the "doorways" of the `2` cells.

Here's a graphical version of what I mean. The red arrows show the doorways I'm trying to detect.

I know there must be a simple(ish) algorithm to calculate this. But I cannot figure it out.

[image: Graphical array depiction]

Comment: Interesting problem. Please explain what the numbers in the square array denote.

Comment: Please show the desired result based on your data sample.

Comment: @RobKwasowski - `1` is road, `2` is room and `0` is nothing

Comment: @PM77-1 - I want the result to show the coordinates of the areas that have "doorways" between `1` and `2` attached. So a group of results like: `[[2,3],[2,4]]` etc

Comment: Does the picture represent the array you've posted?

Comment: Please add the complete result set to your question.

Comment: if 1 is road 2 is room and 0 is nothing, what is the doorways?

Comment: A basic way of doing it will be to find the `2`s and check if there is any `1` around them ([example](https://jsbin.com/tamohanota/edit?js,console)) but I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for because the results that you've mentioned don't make any sense to me.

Comment: How/where are the black lines in the image encoded in the matrix?

Comment: @PM77-1 - I gave you what was required already.

Comment: @SimonCrane - That's irrelevant to the question. It has been answered anyway

Comment: It looks from the picture like the difference between "door" and "boundary between a 1 and a 2" is whether or not there is a black line there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a loop to check the neighbors of every `2` cell in the cardinal directions. If any are `1`, then it's a doorway; add it to the result. The results are returned in `[x, y]` pairs:

```js
const findDoorways = grid => {
  const validDoor = ([x, y]) =>
    grid[y][x] === 2 &&
    [
      grid[y][x-1], grid[y-1][x], 
      grid[y+1][x], grid[y][x+1]
    ].some(e => e === 1)
  ;
  
  return grid.flatMap((row, y) => 
    row.map((_, x) => [x, y]).filter(validDoor)
  );
};

const map = [
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [2,2,2,0,2,2,0,0,0,0],
    [2,2,2,0,2,2,0,0,0,0],
    [0,1,0,0,2,2,1,1,1,0],
    [0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0],
    [0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
];

console.log(findDoorways(map));
```

Or, written plainly:

```js
function validDoor(grid, x, y) {
  return grid[y][x] === 2 && (
    grid[y+1][x] === 1 || grid[y-1][x] === 1 ||
    grid[y][x+1] === 1 || grid[y][x-1] === 1
  );
}

function findDoorways(grid) {
  var doorways = [];
  
  for (var y = 0; y < grid.length; y++) {
    for (var x = 0; x < grid[y].length; x++) {
      if (validDoor(grid, x, y)) {
        doorways.push([x, y]);
      }
    }
  }
  
  return doorways;
}

var map = [
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [2,2,2,0,2,2,0,0,0,0],
    [2,2,2,0,2,2,0,0,0,0],
    [0,1,0,0,2,2,1,1,1,0],
    [0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0],
    [0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
];

console.log(findDoorways(map));
```